# How can I asynchronous databind data to my textblock using XAML

Tags: xaml, data-binding, asynchronous

I have trouble with binding asynchronous data to a textblock.

When I go through my code step by step using F11 it works. But when I just run my app it throws a fault saying:

```
Value cannot be null.
```

It looks like the code runs too fast.

Here's my code:

```
settings.GetSettings();
tbNamePlayer1.Text = settings.player1;
tbNamePlayer2.Text = settings.player2;
```

GetSettings method:

```
StorageFolder sf = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync("XML");
StorageFile st;
try {
    st = await sf.GetFileAsync(filename);
} catch {
    WriteInitialSettings();
}
st = await sf.GetFileAsync(filename);
var reader = XmlReader.Create(st.Path);
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Settings));
settings = (Settings)ser.Deserialize(reader);
player1 = settings.player1;
player2 = settings.player2;
difficulty = settings.difficulty;
win = settings.win;
lose = settings.lose;
```

Comment: cant see any databinding code...

Comment: tbNamePlayer1.Text = settings.player1;
tbNamePlayer2.Text = settings.player2;
Here i try to bind player names to textblocks

Comment: thats no binding code, you simply assing a value to your tbNamePlayer1.Text property

Comment: oke, but how can i do that? Cause, i cant use await in my XAML but it should wait till settings.GetSettings(); is finished. do you have a suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `await` your `GetSettings` method:

```
await settings.GetSettings();
tbNamePlayer1.Text = settings.player1;
tbNamePlayer2.Text = settings.player2;
```

That way your method will (asynchronously) wait until `GetSettings` is complete before assigning the properties.

Answer (score 0):

look at IsAsync or/and Priority Binding in xaml. maybe this can help you out

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-priority-bindings

Comment: Doesn't work, i using XAML and when i can;t use IsAsync. I tried using Task.Delay(3000).Wait(); But doesn't work either

Comment: i dont see any xaml code and binding in your question, but one way do to async stuff, you can find in the link